# Pandas/Excel: Any way to encode the ALT-ENTER / CHAR(10) line break into data when calling DataFrame.to_excel()?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` that I would like to write to Excel. For one column, I have data values that are comma-delimited strings, like `"val1,val2"` or `"val1,val2,val3"`.  When I write that column, I would like to replace the commas with the equivalent of pressing `ALT-ENTER` in Excel, so that there are line breaks between the values.  So, my first example would display as `val1`, then a break within the cell, then `val2`, and so forth. You can also do this in Excel by making the cell a formula and putting `&"char(10)"&` between each value.

I see how I could do this by [coding up formulas via XLSXWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html) and writing cells individually. However I'm hopefully (or lazily) wondering whether there's a way to encode the breaks right into the data so that they would all come out via a simple call to `to_excel()` on the `DataFrame`.

Comment: In XlsxWriter you can use newlines in the string and the `text_wrap` format property to wrap it onto separate lines. [Like this](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_text_wrap). To do it from Pandas you could convert the commas in the strings to `\n` and then apply the `text_wrap` format to the column in the target spreadsheet.

Comment: That absolutely worked!  Care to post as an answer so I can upvote and accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In XlsxWriter you can use newlines in the string and the `text_wrap` format property to wrap it onto separate lines. See this [section of the Format docs](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_text_wrap).

```
wrap_format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})

worksheet.write(0, 0, "Val1\nval2", wrap_format)
```

To do it from Pandas you could convert the commas in the strings to `\n` and then apply the `text_wrap` format to the column in [the target spreadsheet](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html).

Comment: Would it be possible to post a complete working code. From the Dataframe with long strings to the export of the file. I am not very familiar with XlsxWriter.
Thank you very much.

Comment: You will need to open a new question with some sample working code.

Comment: Done. Here is the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50908676/python-how-to-create-multi-line-cells-in-excel-when-exporting-a-pandas-datafram

Answer (score 3):

I still had to do a bit of research after reading the answers here and therefore I wanted to post here a fully working example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['bla\nbla', 'blubb\nblubb']})
with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    cell_format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})
    worksheet.set_column('A:Z', cell_format=cell_format)
```

In particular, I had to figure out that after creating the format object I still need to set it on the respective cells.

Note: You need to `pip install xlsxwriter` before doing it.

Here, again, the link to the [Format Class documenation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format)

Answer (score 0):

for me this sort of code worked perfectly:

```
 liste=['adsf','asdfas','dasdsas','asdfsdaf']
 text=''

 for elem in liste:              
     text=text+elem+'\n'
 ws.Cells(1,1).Value=text
```