# Python: How to create multi line cells in excel when exporting a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the following pandas Dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [['First Line', 'Second line']],
    [['First line', 'second line', 'third line']],
    [['first line']]
])
```

I am trying to export it into an Excel file. However I would like that between each list-element a line break is entered, similar to `ALT-ENTER` in Excel.
So at the end, the excel would look like this:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First you'll need to make sure to have a single string with `'\n'` as a separator instead of the list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['First Line\nSecond line'],
        ['First line\nsecond line\nthird line'],
        ['first line']
    ])
```

You can then call `to_excel` like you normally do, then open the file with openpyxl and set the cells' `.style.alignment.wrap_text` property to `True` like the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370432/writing-multi-line-strings-into-cells-using-openpyxl) suggests.

Alternatively you can wrap `df` with a [`StyleFrame`](https://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) object *(full disclosure: I'm the author of this module, `pip install styleframe` to get it)* that does it for you (`wrap_text=True` is used as default):

```
from styleframe import StyleFrame

df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['First Line\nSecond line'],
        ['First line\nsecond line\nthird line'],
        ['first line']
    ])

StyleFrame(df).to_excel('test.xlsx').save()
```

Comment: looks good! Can you just tell me how to add the index from the pandas Dataframe to the excel, since `index=True` does not work

Comment: @valenzio `StyleFrame(df).to_excel('test.xlsx', index=True).save()` does work for me.

Comment: So I have a 2500 x 4000 pandas dataframe, if I try to export, it my Ram usages explodes (over 8GB). For small dataframes it works fine. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @valenzio I suppose some things aren't as efficient as they could be. Thanks for letting me know, I'll have a look at that.

Comment: That would be awesome, I will look into your first Option as well, but it is a bit tedeious since I never worked with openpyxl

Comment: I turned my Dataframe to StyleFrame in the way suggested, but it throws AttributeError("'Series' object has no attribute 'style'") error. My simplified code:
def save_file(results: DataFrame):
  StyleFrame(results).to_excel("path_to_file").save()

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [`Format.set_text_wrap()` from `xlsxwriter`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_text_wrap):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['First Line\nSecond line'],
    ['First line\nsecond line\nthird line'],
    ['first line']
])

with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
    writer.book.formats[0].set_text_wrap()  # update global format with text wrap
    df.to_excel(writer)
```

Answer (score 0):

nowadays you may just use set_text_wrap() method using ExcelWriter!

```
cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_text_wrap()

worksheet.write(0, 0, "Some long text to wrap in a cell", cell_format)
```

Comment: But where do you define where the actual line break is?