# Concat excel cols and combine rows into one using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data in excel sheet like as below

```
Name    Segment        revenue  Product_id  Status  Order_count      days_ago
Dummy   High value     1000      P_ABC       Yes       2            30 days ago
Dummy   High value     1000      P_CDE       No        1            20 days ago
Dummy   High value     1000      P_EFG       Yes       3            10 days ago
Tammy   Low value      50        P_ABC       No        0            100 days ago
Tammy   Low_value      50        P_DCF       Yes       1            10 days ago
```

I would like to do the below steps in order

a) Concat the columns `Product_id, Status, Order_count` into one column. Use `-` symbol in between values

b) Group the data based on `Name, Segment and revenue`

c) Combine multiple rows for same group into one row (in excel).

I tried something like below

```
df['concat_value'] = df['Product_id'] + " - " + df['Status'] + " - " + df['Order_count'] 
df_group = df.groupby(['Name','Segment','revenue'])
df_nonrepeats = df[df_group['concat_value'].transform('count') == 1]
df_repeats = df[df_group['concat_value'].transform('count') > 1]
```

But am not able to get the expected output as shown below in the excel sheet.

Can you help me on how can I get the below output in excel sheet?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First aggregate values by `\n` for new lines and then add `text_wrap` formating for column `concat_value` - it is mapped to excel columns names by `mapping`.

Solution working if `concat_value` is maximal `26.` column - mapped to `Z` excel column name:

```
import string

df['concat_value'] = df['Product_id'] + " - " + df['Status'] + " - " + df['Order_count'] .astype(str)
df = df.groupby(['Name','Segment','revenue'])['concat_value'].agg('\n'.join).reset_index()
```

---

```
mapping = dict(enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase))
print (mapping)
{0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'F', 6: 'G', 
 7: 'H', 8: 'I', 9: 'J', 10: 'K', 11: 'L', 12: 'M', 13: 'N',
 14: 'O', 15: 'P', 16: 'Q', 17: 'R', 18: 'S', 19: 'T',
 20: 'U', 21: 'V', 22: 'W', 23: 'X', 24: 'Y', 25: 'Z'}

pos = df.columns.get_loc('concat_value')
print (pos)
3

print (mapping[pos])
D

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/72054821/2901002
with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    cell_format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})
    worksheet.set_column(mapping[pos] + ':' + mapping[pos], cell_format=cell_format)
```

Comment: What is the use of mapping variable?

Comment: becaouce need `concat_value` mapping to `D` - fourth column (from pos)